# change the title of web page opened through target= "_blank"

Tags: html, jsf

I want to change the title of web page tab when it is opened through `<h:commandLink target='_blank'>`. How can i set this?

Comment: Not possible, unless you'll use JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one method:

```
url = www.domain.com?title=popupwindowtitle

window.open(url)
```

-popup windows code-

```
<html>
<title><?php echo $_GET['title'']?></title>
</html>
```

---

not sure if there's a way to directly set the title, hope this helps.